Apache Static NextJs Site No read index.txt files
When launching the static Next.js site URL, the /ks/home/index.txt file is read. Although the file exists, no response value is received. This causes a problem where the screen appears but global state cannot be managed.
I deployed it to an Apache web server, and just in case, I also deployed it to an Nginx server. In Nginx, the index.txt file was read normally, and global state management was successful.
Why is global state management not working in Apache?
|ks
|home
|result
| index.html
| index.txt
index.txt?_rsc=1c2a0
Even if I rewrite apache to read all txt files as index.txt, I read whether the file exists,
No response was received.
